# Running local Chainlink Node with Docker - Error: invalid compose project

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose, docker-volume, chainlink

I am trying to run a local Chainlink Node with Docker on my Windows laptop. I use a "Code Along" tutorial on Youtube as foundation but also have tried other sources to get around my problem. Since I have no experience with Docker yet, I am struggling to configure the docker compose file for the chainlink node when I try to use the command "docker compose up". It is possible that my mistake is really easy to spot since I am a beginnner in this... But I fail to figure it out by myself...

Docker compose file:

```
services:
  pg_chainlink:
    image: "postgres"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - database.env
    volumes:
      - \Users\Jacob\Desktop\Bachelorarbeit\Chainlink-Node\chainlink-goerli\data:\var\lib\postgressql\data\
  chainlink:
    image: "smartcontract/chainlink:1.3.0"
    env_file:
      - .env
    depends_on:
      - pg_chainlink  
    ports:
      - "6688:6688"
    volumes:
      - \Users\Jacob\Desktop\Bachelorarbeit\Chainlink-Node\chainlink-goerli\chainlink-volume:\chainlink\
    command: node start --password \chainlink\password.txt --api \chainlink\apicredentials.txt
```

The Error :

```
PS C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop\Bachelorarbeit\Chainlink-Node\chainlink-goerli> docker compose up
service "pg_chainlink" refers to undefined volume \Users\Jacob\Desktop\Bachelorarbeit\Chainlink-Node\chainlink-goerli\data: invalid compose projectPS 
C:\Users\Jacob\Desktop\Bachelorarbeit\Chainlink-Node\chainlink-goerli> docker compose up
service "chainlink" refers to undefined volume \Users\Jacob\Desktop\Bachelorarbeit\Chainlink-Node\chainlink-goerli\chainlink-volume: invalid compose project
```

Either one of the two appears ("pg_chainlink" or "chainlink")

I suspected the slash symbols in my path to be the problem but I tried also the forward slash in many different ways. However, the usage of the double dots to map a path to the volume is also really unfamiliar and weird to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me on WSL2 utilizing docker on Win10.

When running locally both the postgreSQL DB+chainlink container, you need to specify:

`network_mode: "host"`.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    pg-chainlink:
        container_name: pg-chainlink
        image: "postgres"
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        env_file:
            - "database.env"
        volumes:
            - "~/data:/var/lib/postgressql/data/"
    rpc-failover:
        restart: unless-stopped
        container_name: rpc-failover
        image: "fiews/cl-eth-failover"
        command: "wss://goerli.infura.io/ws/v3/<api-key>"
        ports:
          - "4000:4000"
    link-main-node:
        container_name: link-main-node
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: "smartcontract/chainlink:1.4.1-root"
        ports:
          - "6688:6688"
        env_file:
          - ".env"
        volumes:
          - "~/.chainlink:/chainlink"
        command: "local n -p /chainlink/.password -a /chainlink/.api"
        depends_on:
            - "pg-chainlink"
            - "rpc-failover"
        network_mode: "host"
    link-failover-node:
        container_name: link-failover-node
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: "smartcontract/chainlink:1.4.1-root"
        ports:
          - "6688:6688"
        env_file:
          - ".env"
        volumes:
          - "~/.chainlink:/chainlink"
        command: "local n -p /chainlink/.password -a /chainlink/.api"
        depends_on:
            - "pg-chainlink"
            - "rpc-failover"
            - "link-main-node"
        network_mode: "host"
```